# What is the best way of reading/writing structured binary data in C#

Tags: c#

Like in C we could use structure pointers to read or write structured binary data like file headers etc, is there a similar way to do this in C#?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10750/Fast-Binary-File-Reading-with-C -- This article pretty much lays out all of the possible approaches, and the advantages and disadvantages of each.  Sample code is included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) over a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) tends to be the best way in my opinion.

Parsing binary data:

```
byte[] buf = f                     // some data from somewhere
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buf, false)) {   // Read-only
    var br = new BinaryReader(ms);

    UInt32 len = br.ReadUInt32();
    // ...
}
```

Generating binary data:

```
byte[] result;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {   // Expandable
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);

    UInt32 len = 0x1337;
    bw.Write(len);
    // ...

    result = ms.GetBuffer();   // Get the underlying byte array you've created.
}
```

---

They allow you to read and write all of the primitive types you'd need for most file headers, etc. such as `(U)Int16, 32, 64`, `Single`, `Double`, as well as `byte`, `char` and arrays of those.  There is direct support for `string`s, however only if

> The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.

This only seems useful to me if you wrote the string in this way from `BinaryWriter` in this way. It's easy enough however, say your string is prefixed by a DWord length, followed by that many ASCII characters:

```
int len = (int)br.ReadUInt32();
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(len));
```

---

Note that I *do not* have the `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` objects wrapped in a `using()` block. This is because, although they are `IDisposable`, all their `Dispose()` does is call `Dispose()` on the underlying stream (in these examples, the `MemoryStream`).

Since all the `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` are is a set of `Read()`/`Write()` wrappers around the underlying streams, I don't see why they're `IDisposable` anyway. It's just confusing when you try to do The Right Thing and call `Dispose()` on all your `IDisposable`s, and suddenly your stream is disposed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ...which, at the most basic unit, most binary files are comprised of.

Comment: Worth noting that ms.GetBuffer() will return the full allocated buffer for the memory stream which will likely be greater than the number of bytes actually written to it. You can use ms.ToArray() to get just the bytes written via BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 3):

To read arbitrarily-structured data (a `struct`) from a binary file, you first need this:

```
public static T ToStructure<T>(byte[] data)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p = &data[0])
        {
            return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(p), typeof(T));
        }
    };
}
```

You can then:

```
public static T Read<T>(BinaryReader reader) where T: new()
{
    T instance = new T();
    return ToStructure<T>(reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(instance)));
}
```

To write, convert the `struct` object to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

...and then just write the resulting byte array to a file using a `BinaryWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example showing how to read and write data in Binary format to and from a file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace myFileRead
{
    class Program
     {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           // Let's create new data file.
           string myFileName = @"C:\Integers.dat";
            //check if already exists
            if (File.Exists(myFileName))
               {
                Console.WriteLine(myFileName + " already exists in the selected directory.");

                return;
            }

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(myFileName, FileMode.CreateNew);

            // Instantialte a Binary writer to write data

            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            // write some data with bw

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)

            {
                    bw.Write((int)i);
            }

            bw.Close();
            fs.Close();

            // Instantiate a reader to read content from file
            fs = new FileStream(myFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            // Read data from the file

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                //read data as Int32 
                Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
            }
            //close the file 
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();           
       }

    }

}
```